# Network Access for iOS Application difference between Ad-Hoc and In-House

Tags: ios

I have developed an iPad application for one of my clients. The version that is signed for ad-hoc distribution works perfectly. When they sign it for in-house distribution, it no longer can connect to resources in their network. Did anyone have a similar experience before?

Comment: Are you resigning the same build or building another configuration ?

Comment: If you are using entitlements, please check the entitlements file is still at the .ipa payload after re-signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by reading the Encrypted Local Storage. It seems to be a bug.